# Rails "Bootstrap loading button" in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of Users and I want Admin to sent password to those users with a button.
So I saw bootstrap buttons javascript plugin and I used the loading one.

**This is the index.html**

```
<table>
<% @users.each do |user| %>

<td>
 <dl>
  <dt><%= user.name %></dt>
 </dl>
</td>

<td><%= link_to 'show', admin_user_path(user.id) %></td>
<td><%= button_to 'Send password', send_mail_path(user.id), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary", :form => {:"data-loading-text" => "wait ..."}   %></td>

<% end %>
</table>
```

which ends in this html:

```
<table>

<tbody>
 <td>
  <dl><dt>Jonh</dt></dl>
 </td>

 <td><form method="post" data-remote="true" data-loading-text="attendi ..." class="button_to" action="/admin/users/send_mail/26">
   <div><input type="submit" value="send password" class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="hidden" value="bLGRJ1j9Hv75PsN4fuma0NlmYwAbS//1l884ShOotcw=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
   </form></td>
```

And in admin assets/javascript/admin/users I have **index.js.erb**

```
$('.btn').button();

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
  });
});
```

But the loading animation doesn't work. Any suggestion? I am very new to both rails and jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using? If you are in Rails > 3.2 (with asset pipeline) I would encourage you to check whether the file `assets/javascript/admin/users` is actually loaded in your main javascript file and into the page.

Open the page in the browser, check the source and see if the JavaScript code you created is loaded/linked in the header section of the page. Also, I'm not sure why you used the `js.erb` extension.

You can simply use `assets/javascript/admin/users/index.js`. Or even more simpler, avoid too many subfolders when it's not required. Create `/assets/javascript/admin.js` and make sure the `/assets/javascripts/application.js` file includes it.

About the view, the following code

```
<td><%= button_to 'Send password', send_mail_path(user.id), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary", :form => {:"data-loading-text" => "wait ..."}   %></td>
```

can be simplified to

```
<td><%= link_to 'Send password', send_mail_path(user.id), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary", data: { "loading-text" => "wait ..." } %></td>
```

No need to use `button_to` or a form.

Comment: I cleaned it all up just as you suggested and it works now. It seems that the javascript wasn't loaded in the page. 
Grande @Simone ,grazie mille, sto imparando da poco Rails e a volte mi perdo davvero in bicchiere d'acqua